# Pandas why does pd.cut() produce negative values

Tags: python, pandas

Snippet:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'counts':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,14,15]})
test['range'] = pd.cut(test.counts, [0,5,10,15], include_lowest=True)
test
```

Output:

```
    counts  range
0   0   (-0.001, 5.0]
1   1   (-0.001, 5.0]
2   2   (-0.001, 5.0]
3   3   (-0.001, 5.0]
4   4   (-0.001, 5.0]
5   5   (-0.001, 5.0]
6   6   (5.0, 10.0]
7   11  (10.0, 15.0]
8   12  (10.0, 15.0]
9   14  (10.0, 15.0]
10  15  (10.0, 15.0]
```

Can I get `(0, 5.0]` instead of `(-0.001, 5.0]`？ Why does -0.001 show up even if I didn't specify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [the result of `include_lowest=True` internal logic](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py#L346).

You can generate labels by your own in the same way `pd.cuts()` does it when `include_lowest=False`:

```
In [50]: import pandas.core.algorithms as algos

In [51]: labels = pd.Categorical(pd.core.reshape.tile._format_labels(algos.unique(bins), precision=0), 
                                 ordered=True)

In [52]: labels
Out[52]:
[(0, 5], (5, 10], (10, 15]]
Categories (3, interval[int64]): [(0, 5] < (5, 10] < (10, 15]]

In [53]: test['range'] = pd.cut(test.counts, [0,5,10,15],
                                labels=labels,
                                include_lowest=True)

In [54]: test
Out[54]:
    counts     range
0        0    (0, 5]
1        1    (0, 5]
2        2    (0, 5]
3        3    (0, 5]
4        4    (0, 5]
5        5    (0, 5]
6        6   (5, 10]
7       11  (10, 15]
8       12  (10, 15]
9       14  (10, 15]
10      15  (10, 15]
```

Comment: I assume `bins = [0,5,10,15]` which is not shown in your code.

Comment: @Cheng, yes, sorry- forgot to mention that. :)